# Will Ubuntu run in my HP Pavilion - 15-cw1012la

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hp

I am interested in buying a HP Pavilion - 15-cw1012la laptop. However, I do not know if It can run a Ubuntu partition since my current laptop (Another HP Pavilion) cannot run Ubuntu properly.

Does anyone know if it will work?

Thanks.

Comment: I have never seen an HP Pavilion that cannot run Ubuntu properly. Why can't yours?

Comment: I don't know, It won't even run a persisten USB.

Comment: It is impossibe to tell. Vendors install various adapters to the same model.

Comment: No master list of PCs which do and don't is available, so try it. Get Ubuntu's ISO at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a 'flavour' with a different Desktopm from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Comment: Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0

Comment: I am sure it would run, but I have had issues this last year with my HP Envy Ryzen 5 Ubuntu 19.04 - 19.10 , so I would suggest perhaps waiting a couple of months for 19.20 . Issues include USB ports locking up, and not being able to suspend or locked up USB ports when resuming. Not that I know anything special for AMD laptops looming with 19.20  .

Comment: I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 on an HP Pavilion 15-au006ns without success. Ubuntu says it doesn't recognize another OS, and I want to keep the installed Windows 10 indeed.  I have to keep trying.